# Find the Least Squares Estimates

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let

$Y_1=\beta_1+\epsilon_2$

$Y_2=2\beta_1-\beta_2+\epsilon_2$

$Y_3=\beta_1+2\beta_2+\epsilon_3$

where $\epsilon_1$,$\epsilon_2$, and $\epsilon_3$ are uncorrelated random variables with $E(\epsilon_i)=0$ and $Var(\epsilon_i)=\sigma^2$ for $i=1,2,3$

I need help finding the least squares estimates $(\hat{\beta_1},\hat{\beta_2})$ of $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$

All I am asking for is the general procedure and don't need it solved out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the equivalent system as 
$Y=X\beta + \epsilon$ where $X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 2 & -1\\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\beta = \begin{bmatrix} \beta_1\\ \beta_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\epsilon = \begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_1\\ \epsilon_2 \\ \epsilon_3\end{bmatrix}$.
Now the least square estimates of $\beta$ is the solution to equation $X'X\beta=X'Y$ which is always consistent  as column space of X'X and X' are equal
Now $X'X=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0\\ 0 & 5\end{bmatrix} $ and $X'Y=\begin{bmatrix} y_1+2y_2+y_3 \\ -y_2+2y_3\end{bmatrix}$  so least square estimates of $\beta$ are $\hat{\beta}= (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$.  Solving we get 
$\hat{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix} 1/6 & 0\\ 0 & 1/5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_1+2y_2+y_3 \\ -y_2+2y_3\end{bmatrix}$ so  $\hat{\beta}=$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{y_1+2y_2+y_3}{6} \\ \frac{-y_2+2y_3}{5}\end{bmatrix}